# How to get my lost back pack on train

Tags: trains, germany, lost-luggage

On Oct 6 2022, I was traveling on train ICE 1015 from Duets Mess to Mannheim in Germany, where the train arrived at 20:49 to Mannheim, where I forgot my laptop dark blue bag with laptop in the train, which was put in upper shelf of the train. The bag includes Dell black laptop Cor i7, copies of my Master diploma and transcripts and my original UD card by the name XXXX. I also reported to Germany via their website, busy still not found. Is there any alternate methods to find it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there doesn't seem to be a question here

Comment: @ChrisH I think this constitutes a question "Is there any alternate methods to find it?" (but in hindsight was not added by the OP)

Comment: What do you mean "reported to Germany?" Germany is a country, not a train operator. Do you mean you reported the loss of the bag to Deutsche Bahn, the company that runs the train?

Comment: @ChrisH "How to get my lost back pack on train" is a question (just missing the ? at the end

Comment: @Midavalo It was heavily edited to fit into this forum's guidelines.

Comment: Arrange that if a finder contacts UD, that UD does something useful to connect you. Same for other identifying items in the bag,

Answer (score 2):

You can try this https://www.bahn.com/en/contact/lost-luggage

> Is there any alternate methods to find it?

Not really. If the Bahn hasn't found it, it's gone. Sorry.

Comment: Obviously if someone steals your backpack you won’t get it back. If someone found it and passed it to a Bahn employee or an employee finds it (cleaning crew) you’ll get it. It seems you could have been found from the contents of the rucksack, so you should have been contacted. Most likely theft. (Property you find on a train in Germany isn’t legally “lost”, taking it is theft).

Comment: Never attribute to malice what can equally be explained by incompetence.  I wouldn't trust Bahn to manage their own shoe laces.